# Mod_tile alternative for Tomcat?

Tags: openlayers, java, tomcat, josm

I have been running a mod_tile + Mapnik + Renderd + PGSQL solution to host local OSM tiles, as described in the switch2osm guides. I recently put a lot of time in recoding my project to a Tomcat based solution, but want to now move map tile rendering away from Apache2.  If possible maybe have the Carto CSS / Renderd element handled in the Tomcat/Java.

Also because with both APIs are using unsigned localhost HTTPS certs, when using OpenLayers it fails TLS handshake to Apache2 unless I open a new tab and select  continue anyway.

What is the best way to do this?

I have been reading up on JOSM & OSMAPI Java documemtation, but neither of those really look to cover the tile generation much - only the editing of maps. There is also JkMount, but that would still require Apache2 to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

> ... want to now move map tile rendering away from Apache2. If possible maybe have the Carto CSS / Renderd element handled in the Tomcat/Java.

1. For the second part CartoCSS/Renderd, see below

Renderd is an Apache module (in C) so asking to use Tomcat with it is should be difficult (or impossible) as it's only Java.
CartoCSS style is directly related to Mapnik. As [Java bindings for Mapnik](https://github.com/springmeyer/mapnik-jni) are not complete and nearly obsolete (last commit 5 years ago...), don't expect to run a tile server with Java only (except investing time to upgrade everything obsolete)

2. For map tiles rendering purely Java

If you wanted a Java solution to render tiles, you could use GeoServer but it would mean restarting from scratch as Mapnik styles are not usable in GeoServer and only one or two styles to display OSM tiles are available (and not well maintained)

My personal opinion would be to not waste time and money and keep to the most common solutions: Java nearly does not any ecosystem to render OSM tiles specifically (at the moment at least).

> Also because with both APIs are using unsigned localhost HTTPS certs, when using OpenLayers it fails TLS handshake to Apache2 unless I open a new tab and select continue anyway.

For your concern about https certificate, look at [Let's encrypt initiative](https://letsencrypt.org/) to get free SSL certificate on your server.